# Does AWS SDK for JavaScript support "eu-west-2" region?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

inside region_config.json in aws-sdk I can only see "eu-west-1"

Does AWS SDK for JavaScript support "eu-west-2" region ?

Answer (score 0):

Regions endpoints are made as similar as possible to avoid multiple configuration keys.
In your case, you can just add the following line in the [region_config.json](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/lib/region_config_data.json) to add the ability for s3:

```
"eu-west-2/s3": "s3dash",
```

Other service are generic enough to understand directly at call time how to route your request.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. As rightly told by you I could test other service like sqs and it automatically supported "eu-west-2". For s3 is it that the user of aws-sdk-js should add this in region_config.json or else I think it should be added by default by aws-sdk-js developers ?

Comment: @vibhutipithwa it should definitely be added in the SDK by AWS, probably a work in progress. If you really rely on it, you can submit a PR on Github.